# I am confused about --make-{shared,slave,private,unbindable} flags of the mount command

Tags: command-line, mount, mountpoint

I am confused about `--make-shared`, `--make-slave`, `--make-private` and `--make-unbindable` flags of the `mount` command.

Can someone please explain in simple words , what each flag do ?
and what is the difference between them ?

Comment: This should explain it all clearly for you... https://linux.die.net/man/1/make

Comment: Does the full documentation hidden away at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt help?

Comment: You don’t usually need to set these unless in special situations that involve using the same mount points interchably to mount different filesystems in different user spaces utilizing  e.g. `pivot_root` or `chroot` during a single system boot session like in system maintenance situations … See an example of that here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1416932 … @MartinThornton other than this missing piece of info, your linked resource seems on target and I encourage you to make an answer in layman’s terms from all that so folks like me can easily find and understand it :-)

Comment: Folks voting to close this question as unclear or unfocused .., Please, don’t … This is as clear and focused as it ever going to be … It’s clear about `mount` and focused on four of it’s options that happen to be rarely discussed and IMO is worth its own Q&A on this site.

Comment: I see you edited your question which initially had examples of those options with `r` recursive in them like `--make-rshared` and so on … Well that is what it means i.e. recursively apply that option to already existing sub-mounts under the source argument for `mount`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These flags to the `mount` command are advanced features which modify the way bind-mounts work.  They also have the same effects on mount-namespaces,  and this is sometimes used by `systemd` to allow a process to have its own private mounts.

The `--make-unbindable` flag prevents any later bind-mounting of either part or the whole of a mount:

```
mount --make-unbindable /master

#Both of these will fail
mount --rbind /master /slave
mount --rbind /master/subdir /slave
```

The other flags effect how changes to submounts within a mount are synchronized between future bind-mounts and namespaces.  The use of `--rbind` instead of `--bind` is still needed to recursively share all *existing* submounts with the bind mount, except those made unbindable as above.

Like `--bind`, all these flags also have variants with an `r` prefix which are recursively applied to all contained mounts.

The `--make-[r]shared` flag (the initial state with systemd) enables synchronisation between a master mount and future copies.  By example, for an existing mount at `/master`, both `master-submount` and `slave-submount` will be mounted under both `/master` and `/slave`:

```
mount --make-rshared /master
mount --rbind /master /slave
mount /dev/$DEVICE /master/master-submount
mount /dev/$DEVICE /slave/slave-submount
```

The `--make-[r]private` flag stops further synchronisation. This is irreversible for any *existing* shares.  Continuing the above example below, unmounting `/master/master-submount` and `/slave/slave-submount` will *not* now unmount the copies at `/slave/master-submount` and `/master/slave-submount`:

```
mount --make-rprivate /slave
umount /master/master-submount
umount /slave/slave-submount
```

The `--make-[r]slave` flag can be used to break only updates *to* others, but still receive them.  If `rslave` had been used instead of `rprivate` above, `/master/slave-submount` would still not be unmounted by `/slave`, but `/slave/master-submount` would also have been unmounted by `/master`.

---

The full documentation for these flags is not in the `man` page, but is available at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt.

Comment: Nicely done ... Although I would (*in addition to VFS namespaces of course*) emphasize switching between userspaces in a running system as without the latter, the former will almost have no practical applicable challenge cases IMHO ... The [VFS(*Virtual FileSystem*)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/vfs.txt) is the kernels implementation of a software layer to present the Actual FileSystem(*low-level on disk*) to userspace(*s*) as `vfsmount` ... So, unless switching between userspaces, I hardly can think of user need to set such `vfsmount`'s attributes.