# extend/resize ubuntu partition in dual boot system without external usb/cd drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I am using a dual boot system(ubuntu22.04+windows11). I wanted to extend the Ubuntu partition size.So first I created some unallocated memory from the ubuntu partition. Now I want to add this unallocated space to my ubuntu part.

Most of the solution here suggest to use gparted for that. But for that, I need an usb drive/pendrive. Can I somehow do that without any external pendrive?

Comment: "*Can I somehow do that without any external pendrive?*" ... I don't know if you can, but it can be done if you move certain needed system parts into memory i.e. RAM and then unmount your root partition, resize it and bring it back to life again ... Please see something similar here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1416932 describing dealing with that remotely via SSH ... Your system is on a local machine so it should be much easier and safer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increase the size of a partition you are currently working on, the the partition needs be unmounted when performing an operation like this. So from within the running Ubuntu it is not possible to extend a partition.

You need some external tool like running Gparted from an USB drive.

Theoretically you could use the Windows Disk Manager, but it is not really good in dealing with other file systems than the one supported by Windows. So this cannot be recommended.